# how i can write a trigger that take just some special word

Tags: sql, postgresql

```sql
CREATE TABLE "SomeTable"
(
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  g CHARACTER(1),
  PRIMARY KEY (bid )
);
```

how i can write trigger that just user can insert f , m  for gender
and for other raise err

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use a trigger for this.  You use a `check` constraint:

```
alter table someTable add constraint chk_someTable_gender
    check (gender in ('f', 'm'));
```

I'm going to leave aside the discussion of how many genders you should actually be representing.

Comment: thanks man.but can you create trigger(just for learning perpose) :-)